# Is it possible to mimic Vue's component registration with React?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Using Vue, you can register a component like such:

```js
Vue.component('my-app', require('./vue/MyApp.vue').default);
```

and then in any HTML file you can just call `<my-app></my-app>`

```html
<my-app></my-app>
```

and Vue automatically picks it up as a component, passes down props, and renders it.

Currently, in React, the only thing I can find is that I must initialize all component instances with `React.createElement` or `createRoot()` and exactly specify which container they will go into.

There is a lot to wish for in React's implementation for a partially decoupled website.  So in Twig + Vue, I could do something like

```html
{% for message in messages %}
  <status-message v-bind:message="message"></status-message>
{% endfor %}
```

Above, it combines a twig loop with vue components.  Thus, directly from the server, I can return a vue component without having to initialize it in some js file.  Trying to mimic the above with React, I think I would have to start using `.getAttribute()` to pass down props to a component (and handling child components seems to also be a problem) while writing a complicated JS script to dynamically render all possible components on the page from a list of selectors.  This is a lot more manual than Vue where it can just automatically detect tags once you register them.

Ideally, I could just write the following in Twig + React:

```html
<ToastContainer position="top-end">
  {% for message in messages %}
    <Toast>{{ message }}</Toast>
  {% endfor %}
</ToastContainer>
```

And then, all messages would be displayed within a Toast, with `position` being passed down to the `<ToastContainer>` component.  As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to pass props or child components like you can in Vue.  And since the props have to be injected with JS, the variables like the message itself needs to be passed from PHP to JS rather than being able to pass them as HTML attributes.  Without an easy way, my only thought is to start reading attributes via `.getAttribute()` and then passing those as props through `createElement()` which sounds like something that has probably already been done before.

Is it possible to mimic Vue's Component Registration with React?

Comment: Perhaps one option would be to put the React component (or component tree) inside a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)? It might take a bit of boilerplate to do something like this, but perhaps it could achieve the kind of decoupling you want?

Comment: That's an interesting thought.  It does seem like it would be a lot of boilerplate just from some of the examples but I could see it being a robust solution, although I'm not familiar with Web Components at all so there might be a learning curve